# C# Get List of Time 00AM to 23PM on to List

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Scenario:
I'm trying to populate the C# List with all the time in a day as shown in example below:

> 00AM to 23PM.

Could someone please help me whether this can be achieved from LINQ or similar?

Thanks.

Comment: show us some code with your efforts in doing this, or at least your actual list.

Comment: So you want a list of `DateTime` or a list of `String`?

Comment: 23PM does not make sense, weather it should be 00 PM or just 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(); 
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(date, 24)
                       .Select((x, i) => x.AddHours(i).ToString("HH tt"));
```

Comment: Thanks I have to accept the other answer as it closes meet my requirement

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want the difference between two succesive values to be one second, you can use this query:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 23 * 3600).Select(x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)).ToList();
```

The number `23 * 3600` stands for total number of seconds between 00:00 and 23:00. If you want to have values from minute to minute, use this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 23 * 60).Select(x => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x)).ToList();
```